# HTML table filtering by text and image

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have HTML table with text and icons. I try to make it possible to filter/search by text or/and image. Image filtering is working now I am wondering how to add text search functionality.

```
<div id="usertable">
<div class="choicebox">
    <div id="choicebox">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <a id="all">ALL</a>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="admin" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/windows-7-general/256/administrator-icon.png" width="30" height="30">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="member" src="http://blog.getjobber.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Users-Image.png" width="30" height="30">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="search"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="userbox">
    <table id="tablelist">
        <tr class="rowHeader">
            <td colspan="7">
                <div class="firstrow">
                    <div>User List</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rowHeader">
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>User ID</td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>Organisation</td>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Extra</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>2325</td>
            <td>Admin Password</td>
            <td>Park</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>Admin Status</td>
            <td><img class="admin"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/windows-7-general/256/administrator-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dave</td>
            <td>5598</td>
            <td>Member Password</td>
            <td>Club</td>
            <td>Member</td>
            <td>Admin Status</td>
            <td><img class="user" src="http://blog.getjobber.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Users-Image.png" width="30" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>6587</td>
            <td>Admin Password</td>
            <td>Garden</td>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>Admin Status</td>
            <td><img class="admin"  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconshock/windows-7-general/256/administrator-icon.png" width="30" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>2254</td>
            <td>Member Password</td>
            <td>Parking</td>
            <td>Member</td>
            <td>Admin Status</td>
            <td><img class="user" src="http://blog.getjobber.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Users-Image.png" width="30" height="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS part looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
alternateRowColor();

$('#admin').on('click', function () {
    $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0);
        if ($.trim($(this).find('img').attr('class')) != 'admin') {
            $(this).not('.rowHeader').hide(0);
        }
    });
    alternateRowColor();
});
$('#member').on('click', function () {
    $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0);
        if ($.trim($(this).find('img').attr('class')) != 'user') {
            $(this).not('.rowHeader').hide(0);
        }
    });
    alternateRowColor();
});
$('#all').on('click', function () {
    $('#tablelist tr').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0);
    });
    alternateRowColor();
    });
});
function alternateRowColor() {
    var i = 0;
    $('#tablelist tr:visible').each(function () {
        if (i % 2 === 0) $(this).removeClass('odd').addClass('even');
        else $(this).removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
        i++;
    });
}
```

Here is JSFidle for this http://jsfiddle.net/zaga/j8hw023o/7/

Comment: what do you want to search?..which field?

Comment: text input should search whole table, while image filters should be applied to particular row

Answer (score 1):

you can do,

```
$("#search").on('keyup', function () {
    var input = this.value.toLowerCase();

    $("#usertable table tr:hidden").show();
    $("#tablelist tr:not(.rowHeader)").filter(function () {
        return $(this).find("td:first-child").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(input) < 0;
    }).hide();    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/j8hw023o/8/)**

Comment: somehow in text input does not give any proper results. Desirable behaviour is to be able to apply image filtering and do text search on top of it, only for visible table rows. Any idea?